# Grab theme from local storage before page is rendered in react

Tags: reactjs, darkmode

I am building a small web application with react and have also included a ThemeSwitcher component. This component contains the visual aspects, i.e. the toggle, as well as a script to switch the theme and a script to access local storage. The ThemeSwitcher component then gets imported into the Header component, which in turn gets imported into index.js

When toggling from the dark-theme (default) to the light-theme, this information is saved to local storage:

```
let currentTheme = "dark-theme";

function switchTheme() {
        const body = document.querySelector("body");
        const transitionChecker = document.querySelector("#theme-selector");
    
        body.classList.add("transition");
        body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
        transitionChecker.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
            body.classList.remove("transition");
        });
        currentTheme === "dark-theme"
            ? (currentTheme = "light-theme")
            : (currentTheme = "dark-theme");
    
        localStorage.setItem("storedTheme", currentTheme);
    }
```

I am accessing this value on page load using:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    let storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("storedTheme");
    if (storedTheme === "light-theme") switchTheme();
});
```

This works more or less as intended. However, on page load the dark-theme is shown for a split second, before switching over to the light-theme.

Is there any way to grab the intended theme before the page is rendered in order to avoid the default theme from flashing through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some playing around, I believe to have a solution that works for me. I basically just put this right at the beginning of my App.js (which gets rendered in index.js) just before declaring the actual component:

```
//get stored theme right at the beginning
let currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("storedTheme");
if (!currentTheme) currentTheme = "dark-theme"; // if no theme was stored, set to default --> dark-theme

document.querySelector("body").classList.add(currentTheme);
```

How I arrived at this solution:

- I got started using create-react-app, so switching over to Next.js
  wasn't an option
- Tried some things with setTimeOut, but couldn't get it to work
- Tried using `useEffect()`, but this still let the dark theme flash
  through if the light-theme chosen previously
- Moving the code outside of the actual App component, but still
  locating it within App.js worked.

`switchTheme()` was also moved to App.js and is located at the very end.

Not sure if this is a proper solution or if it just gives the browser this extra split second to grab the stored theme before it actually gets rendered. But it worked for me.

Comment: Ahh.. I literally forgot we can write JS outside of  `React` . Well done.

Comment: @loocd, I have this exact issue. But above code still shows the default browser background for split second before rendering my theme background. Not sure if I'm missing anything else

Comment: @Gangula, have you moved the part where you grab the theme from local storage entirely outside of the actual react component? this is what it looks like in my case: https://ibb.co/3SY0QLt
for more details you can also check out the site: http://http.nkia.loocd.ch/

Comment: My bad. I forgot that I had a `transition-delay` for the `background-color`